# Fabric error: Invalid Login

Tags: authentication, twitter-fabric

1. Created a Fabric account
2. Downloaded and launched Fabric app (on Mac)
3. Tried to login into Fabric app:

   > Result:
   >   *Invalid Login*

At this point, on Fabric website I am shown as logged in (my name and email stay on the top-right)

4. Logged out from Fabric website
5. Tried to log back in:

> Result: "Oops! Looks like your email or password is incorrect."

6. Tried to sign up again with the same email:

> Result: *This email address is already being used. Use another email
>   address or Sign in below.*

100% sure the credentials are correct.
Any solution/thoughts/links/experience upon this issue is highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds much more like a Fabric bug or issue then an actual solvable Stack Overflow question. I would maybe suggest contacting their support somehow and see what they say about it. Maybe someone has run into this before and has a solution but I would suggest figuring out a way to contact them about it. Not much we can do about their server bugs and issues.

Comment: @CharlieFish it's a real bug, someone could run into this issue, AND, if they managed to solve it, they can post an answer. No one asks you to clear Fabric's server-side bugs, but if it is one - let it to be confirmed by someone who solved it. Thanks for downvoting though.

Comment: Who said I down voted? Just sharing my opinions and viewpoint on the question. Just thought as well as posting on SO contacting them might also help. I wish you the best of luck tho and hopefully it gets fixed.

Comment: Funny: I created a Fabric account for Crashlytics and failed to log in. Maybe Fabric should install Crashlytics as well?

Comment: @CharlieFish could not find a support email of Fabric. Found one of Crashllytics and submitted the issue. Waitnig...

Comment: Sadly I haven't used Fabric before. Again I mean no disrespect. I'm just trying to help give suggestions to solve your problem. If you don't want suggestions or comments maybe don't post on Stack Overflow. But seriously good luck. Hopefully someone knows your answer or you can find a solution.

Comment: @CharlieFish dude, don't burn, I don't blame on you. "maybe don't post on Stack Overflow" - wow, it looks like you take it too personal, maybe you shouldn't answer on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Considering you accused me of down voting your question with 0 proof that is kinda uncool. Please go back and read what I said. IF you don't want suggestions or comments maybe don't post. If is the key word there. Hopefully it all works out.